# how to find most recent records for every group in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

this is my hive table

```
       id                    name                   starttime(datatype string )

    0000031               workflows_status       Thu, 18 Feb 2016 14:21:38 GMT  
    0000030               workflows_status       Thu, 18 Feb 2016 14:16:28 GMT  
    0000029               workflows_status       Thu, 18 Feb 2016 14:07:25 GMT  
    0000336               hive_test              Tue, 16 Feb 2016 09:27:54 GMT  
    0000335               hive_test              Tue, 16 Feb 2016 09:17:52 GMT  
    0000334               hive_test              Tue, 16 Feb 2016 09:00:26 GMT
```

i want hive query to get the following results

```
    id               name                   starttime

    0000031          workflow_status        Thu, 18 Feb 2016 14:21:38 GMT
    0000336          hive_test              Tue, 16 Feb 2016 09:27:54 GMT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get your required output using below query:

> select * from (select id, name, starttime, rank() over(partition by
>   name order by unix_timestamp(starttime, 'EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z')
>   desc) as rnk  from hive_table) a  where a.rnk=1;

Answer (score 2):

Hive allow such operations through [Windowing and Analytics Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics).

Using **RANK()** function with **OVER** clause, you can achieve your desire result. Over clause will group by results on specified column name and then Rank = 1 will get first result in each group. This is analogues to `ROWNUM = 1` in oracle.

```
select * from (
 select 
   id, 
   name, 
   starttime, 
   rank() over ( partition by name order by starttime) desc ) as rank_alias 
 from hive_table
) a where a.rank_alias = 1;
```